# Rotation matrix in yo-yo problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, tensor-calculus

I need to solve the yo-yo problem **not in the normal sense**. Instead, I need to include **the position vector $r$ and rotation matrix $R$. Assume the yo-yo is rotating in the plane.**

In the problem yo-yo is made of two identical cylinders of radius $R$, thickness $h$ and mass $M$, and the yo-yo is let go.

**My attempt:**

In the description of asteroid problem in space, where the  $r$ is in $R^3$ and transformation $\phi$ is  $\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0&{ - {x_3}}&{{x_2}}\\
{{x_3}}&0&{ - {x_1}}\\
{ - {x_2}}&{{x_1}}&0
\end{array}} \right)$.
The normal problem has 6 degrees of freedom.

**Here comes my problem**, how to define transformation $\phi$ in yo-yo problem. 
Is the inertia tensor $J_{\Omega}$ is a $2\times 2$ or $3 \times 3$ matrix?
The problem has only two degrees of freedom, so I assign the origin of system in the center of yo-yo's first position, the position vector is in $R^1$. 
The rotation of the yo-yo is just rotation around the one-point.

Can I just follow the method in the asteroid example in proving Euler's equation of solid body motion? **does the lie algebra thing from which we derive the Euler's equation of solid body motion still works?**  Is there anything I need to change for this example?

So can anyone help me with this? Thanks so much!

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "The asteroid problem" is not a common problem that we all know.  The transformation matrix you write down looks more like an element of the Lie algebra (which is not a transformation, strictly speaking), rather than an element of the Lie group (which is).  But generally, yes you can treat this problem using more general methods if you wish; 3-dimensional calculations will still work, even though the problem is essentially 2-dimensional.

Comment: The rotation matrix that you deleted for some reason was right.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can specialise the derivation of the three dimensional Euler equations for your special case. However, unless you are expressly asked to do this, I doubt that your teacher means for you to take this path because it is very much an overkill. The yoyo is spinning in a plane about its axis of symmetry. The inertia tensor is now a simple scalar $J$: the nett torque $\tau$ on the yoyo (assume anticlockwise about the +z axis is positive) is related to its angular speed $\omega$ (assume same sign convention) by $\tau = J\,\dot{\omega}$. The matrix you have written down is the time *derivative* of a rotation matrix (relative to the initial axes). Knock out one row and the corresponding column (because you're rotating only about one axis) and you're left with a matrix of the form $\omega\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$; it exponentiates to the the rotation matrix $\left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{array}\right)$ (this is what you need to use) where $\theta(t) = \int_0^t \omega(u)\,\mathrm{d}u$. Then the equations of motion $\tau = J\,\dot{\omega}$, $F_x=m\,\dot{x}$ and $F_y = m\,\dot{y}$, where $x,\,y$ define the position of the yoyo's centre of mass.

---

**Questions from OP**

> Thanks for your answer! I don't understand why the inertial tensor J is a scalar? I thought it is a cylinder rotating about an axis and the form is scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/MomentofInertiaCylinder.html Could you please explain it for me?

As you can see from your link, the inertia tensor is when one co-ordinate axis is along the cylinder's axis of symmetry is diagonal. Your problem constrains the cylinder to rotate about its axis of symmetry, so you can forget about the $xx$ and $yy$ components of the tensor and simply use $\tau = \frac{1}{2}\,M\,R^2\,\dot{\omega}$. Strictly speaking, though, it is, as you still a tensor, it's simply that the constrained motion lets you treat it as a scalar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't understand why the inertial tensor $J$ is a scalar? I thought it is a cylinder rotating about an axis and the form is http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/MomentofInertiaCylinder.html Could you please explain it for me?

Comment: @Sherry Please see my answer at the end.